# BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher doesn't receive Advertisement payload

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetoothleadvertisementwatcher

I'm trying send Information from Device A to Device B using Bluetooth Low Energy Advertisements.
In order to receive the broadcasts, I'm using Windows UWP's Bluetooth Low Energy Library (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/ble-beacon)

My received advertisements should include Information, but they don't. I tried to use BluetoothLEAdvertisementDataSection and BluetoothLEManufacturerData. Both aren't working. If I receive the Advertisement, the BluetoothLEAdvertisementDataSection doesn't include my information and the BluetoothLEManufacturerData is just empty.

This is what I receive:

```
Address: 0x2462ABE13A7E; Name:CH1234; RSSI: -49 
ManufacturerDataLength: 0 
ManufacurerData: []  
DataSectionsLength: 4 
DataSections: [0x06] [0x43-48-31-32-33-34] [0x03] [0x20-00-40-00]
```

The DataSections are about DataType 0x01, DataType 0x09, DataType 0x0A and 0x12

Is there any way to get the raw advertisement message? Or any other way to get this information?

I tried to receive Information from Advertisements using bluepy on Linux and it is working. Therefore the problem must be within this library.

This is my Code: https://pastebin.com/rxcrjhpj
There is not mutch. Just the BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher and printing the received Information.

///Edit
I fixxed it. The mistake was within sending the broadcast.
I use nkolban's ESP32 BLE Library, there are two functions. One called "BLEAdvertisementData.setManufacturerData" and the other one "BLEAdvertisementData.addData". However by using "addData" it looks like the broadcast frame gets messed up somehow. It's working if I just use "setManufacturerData" instead of "addData"

Comment: What data type do you advertise?

Comment: What do you mean with "DataType"? do you mean https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/generic-access-profile/ or do you mean string/integer/byte...?

Comment: I mean advertisement data type as described by the link you provided.

Comment: Manufacturer Specific Data (0xFF)

Comment: Actually I just fixxed it somehow. I'll get into it and write my solution to this post.